How to add more regions to the provideFunctions function in Angular Firebase?
I'm using the provideFunctions function in my Angular Firebase project to initialize the Cloud Functions for my application. However, I need to add more regions to support my application's global user base. Currently, my code looks like this:
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getApp, getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from 'firebase/app';
import { connectFunctionsEmulator as connectFunctionsEmulatorCore, getFunctions as getFunctionsCore } from 'firebase/functions';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export const provideFunctions = () => {
  const functions = getFunctionsCore(getApp(), 'asia-southeast2');
  if (environment.useEmulators) {
    connectFunctionsEmulatorCore(functions, 'localhost', 5001);
  }
  return functions;
};

This code initializes the Cloud Functions for the asia-southeast2 region. How can I modify this code to add support for multiple regions, such as us-central1 and europe-west1? I need to be able to call the appropriate Cloud Function based on the user's location.
I've tried searching for a solution, but I couldn't find a clear way to achieve this. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

You will have to call initializeApp() once for each region, then use each of the generated FirebaseApp objects to get a new Functions object for that region (using your getFunctionsCore() function).
Then you will have to figure out how your application will use each of these independently configured Functions objects based on the region you want to run against.
